# What is the difference between these two kind of requiring in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, syntax, require

In a tutorial I saw a code like this:

```
var session = require('express-session');
var FileStore = require('session-file-store')(session);
```

And another code like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
```

But I think I can write the first code like this:

```
var sessionFileStore = require('session-file-store');
var FileStore = sessionFileStore.session;
```

And the second one like:

```
var Schema = require('mongoose')(Schema);
```

OR

```
var Schema = require('mongoose').Schema;
```

I just wanted to ask for sure, are these two kind of writing equal or there are some differences?

I also like to know what is the meaning/difference if I use something like below for the second command:

```
var Schema = require('mongoose')('Schema');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the same. `require` is a normal function, which returns a value. So, if that value is also a function, you can immediately call it, or use one of its properties if it is an object.

However, in the second case, `require('mongoose')(Schema)` will cause two errors:

1. Here `require` returns an object, not a function, so you can't invoke it.
2. You are using the variable `Schema` which has not been defined yet, and passing it as an argument to a function.

In the second case, the right way to put it in a single line is `var Schema = require('mongoose').Schema;`

And in the first case, I think that the correct way is `var FileStore = sessionFileStore(session);` I assume here `session` is a global variable, or has been defined previously.

Comment: Thank you very much! About the first case you are right, I forgot to add `var session = require('express-session');` line. But what about following line? What is the meaning of this: `var Schema = require('mongoose')('Schema');`

Comment: Well, in that case, you would be calling de function returned by `require('mongoose')` and passing it the string `Schema` as an argument, but that shouldn't work. `require('mongoose')` returns an object, so such a line would throw an error (_Object is not a function_). You must use: `require('mongoose').Schema`

Comment: May you help me alos understand what is the difference between `session` in `var FileStore = require('session-file-store')(session);` and `Router()` in `var router = express.Router()` ?

Comment: It's better if you make another question for that. I'll gladly help you there, so this question doesn't get bloated with other stuff